# spring-cloud-dataflow: Stream Deployments Fail on OSX

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am unable to deploy and execute a basic `http | log` stream following the 
[getting-started stream guide](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/stream-developer-guides/getting-started/stream/):

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/2.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-dataflow-server/docker-compose.yml;
export DATAFLOW_VERSION=2.1.0.RELEASE;
export SKIPPER_VERSION=2.0.2.RELEASE;
docker-compose up;
open http://localhost:9393/dashboard/#/streams/create;
echo "Then, create a stream via text input: `http | log`"
echo "Then, deploy the stream. The deployment fails with exit code 137."
```

I get the green "Successfully deployed stream definition".
The status shows as "Deploying", but it never fully deploys.
There are no `ERROR` messages in the logs, in the UI, or in the network requests.

Here is the console output of `docker-compose up` after I deploy the stream.

```
skipper              | 2019-05-24 22:31:53.363  INFO 1 --- [io-7577-exec-10] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : started UPGRADE UPGRADE_DEPLOY_TARGET_APPS_SUCCEED UPGRADE_DEPLOY_TARGET_APPS UPGRADE_START UPGRADE_DELETE_SOURCE_APPS UPGRADE_CHECK_TARGET_APPS UPGRADE_WAIT_TARGET_APPS UPGRADE_CANCEL UPGRADE_DEPLOY_TARGET_APPS_FAILED UPGRADE_CHECK_CHOICE UPGRADE_EXIT INSTALL INSTALL_INSTALL INSTALL_EXIT ERROR DELETE DELETE_DELETE DELETE_EXIT ROLLBACK ROLLBACK_START ROLLBACK_EXIT_INSTALL ROLLBACK_EXIT ROLLBACK_EXIT_UPGRADE ROLLBACK_CHOICE INITIAL ERROR_JUNCTION  /  / uuid=f1ca31f2-ddcf-4203-88c8-de367c104151 / id=http-log-ingest-5
skipper              | 2019-05-24 22:31:53.504  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-1] o.s.c.s.s.s.StateMachineConfiguration    : Entering state ObjectState [getIds()=[INITIAL], getClass()=class org.springframework.statemachine.state.ObjectState, hashCode()=1038812346, toString()=AbstractState [id=INITIAL, pseudoState=org.springframework.statemachine.state.DefaultPseudoState@12280a0a, deferred=[], entryActions=[], exitActions=[org.springframework.cloud.skipper.server.statemachine.ResetVariablesAction@6fd12c5], stateActions=[], regions=[], submachine=null]]
skipper              | 2019-05-24 22:31:53.540  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-3] o.s.c.s.s.s.StateMachineConfiguration    : Entering state StateMachineState [getIds()=[INSTALL], toString()=AbstractState [id=INSTALL, pseudoState=null, deferred=[], entryActions=[], exitActions=[], stateActions=[], regions=[], submachine=INSTALL_INSTALL INSTALL_EXIT  /  / uuid=fbcafd74-2879-4e86-81da-8372a5be31be / id=http-log-ingest-5], getClass()=class org.springframework.statemachine.state.StateMachineState]
skipper              | 2019-05-24 22:31:53.576  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-3] o.s.c.s.s.s.StateMachineConfiguration    : Entering state ObjectState [getIds()=[INSTALL_INSTALL], getClass()=class org.springframework.statemachine.state.ObjectState, hashCode()=1643670584, toString()=AbstractState [id=INSTALL_INSTALL, pseudoState=org.springframework.statemachine.state.DefaultPseudoState@12493450, deferred=[], entryActions=[org.springframework.cloud.skipper.server.statemachine.InstallInstallAction@149debbb], exitActions=[], stateActions=[], regions=[], submachine=null]]
skipper              | 2019-05-24 22:31:54.117  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-3] o.s.c.d.spi.local.LocalAppDeployer       : Preparing to run an application from org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:log-sink-kafka:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE. This may take some time if the artifact must be downloaded from a remote host.
skipper              | 2019-05-24 22:31:54.179  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-3] o.s.c.d.spi.local.LocalAppDeployer       : Command to be executed: /opt/openjdk/bin/java -jar /root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/log-sink-kafka/2.1.1.RELEASE/log-sink-kafka-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar
skipper              | 2019-05-24 22:31:54.203  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-3] o.s.c.d.spi.local.LocalAppDeployer       : Deploying app with deploymentId http-log-ingest-5.log-v1 instance 0.
skipper              |    Logs will be in /tmp/spring-cloud-deployer-3633167379998955348/http-log-ingest-5-1558737114000/http-log-ingest-5.log-v1
skipper              | 2019-05-24 22:31:54.310  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-3] o.s.c.d.spi.local.LocalAppDeployer       : Preparing to run an application from org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:http-source-kafka:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE. This may take some time if the artifact must be downloaded from a remote host.
skipper              | 2019-05-24 22:31:54.312  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-3] o.s.c.d.spi.local.LocalAppDeployer       : Command to be executed: /opt/openjdk/bin/java -jar /root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/http-source-kafka/2.1.0.RELEASE/http-source-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar
skipper              | 2019-05-24 22:31:54.313  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-3] o.s.c.d.spi.local.LocalAppDeployer       : Deploying app with deploymentId http-log-ingest-5.http-v1 instance 0.
skipper              |    Logs will be in /tmp/spring-cloud-deployer-3633167379998955348/http-log-ingest-5-1558737114208/http-log-ingest-5.http-v1
skipper              | 2019-05-24 22:31:54.369  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-3] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : stopped org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor@2c9d52c5
skipper              | 2019-05-24 22:31:54.370  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-3] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : stopped INSTALL_INSTALL INSTALL_EXIT  /  / uuid=fbcafd74-2879-4e86-81da-8372a5be31be / id=http-log-ingest-5
skipper              | 2019-05-24 22:31:54.371  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-3] o.s.c.s.s.s.StateMachineConfiguration    : Entering state ObjectState [getIds()=[INITIAL], getClass()=class org.springframework.statemachine.state.ObjectState, hashCode()=1038812346, toString()=AbstractState [id=INITIAL, pseudoState=org.springframework.statemachine.state.DefaultPseudoState@12280a0a, deferred=[], entryActions=[], exitActions=[org.springframework.cloud.skipper.server.statemachine.ResetVariablesAction@6fd12c5], stateActions=[], regions=[], submachine=null]]
skipper              | 2019-05-24 22:31:54.372  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-3] o.s.c.s.s.s.SkipperStateMachineService   : setting future value org.springframework.cloud.skipper.domain.Release@279e0d49
skipper              | 2019-05-24 22:31:54.373  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-3] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : started org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor@2c9d52c5
skipper              | 2019-05-24 22:31:54.373  INFO 1 --- [eTaskExecutor-3] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : started INSTALL_INSTALL INSTALL_EXIT  /  / uuid=fbcafd74-2879-4e86-81da-8372a5be31be / id=http-log-ingest-5
mysql_1              | 2019-05-24T22:32:45.648870Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 4662ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=2 and evicted=0, during the time.)
zookeeper_1          | [2019-05-24 22:32:52,733] INFO Expiring session 0x10001d6560e0001, timeout of 6000ms exceeded (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
mysql_1              | 2019-05-24T22:33:08.378945Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 7338ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=1 and evicted=0, during the time.)
mysql_1              | 2019-05-24T22:33:24.272169Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 5118ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)
zookeeper_1          | [2019-05-24 22:33:28,644] INFO Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x10001d6560e0001 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
kafka_1              | [2019-05-24 22:33:40,709] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=1001] Removed 0 expired offsets in 2216 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
kafka_1              | [2019-05-24 22:33:49,359] WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 58623ms for sessionid 0x10001d6560e0001 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
kafka_1              | [2019-05-24 22:33:56,611] TRACE [Controller id=1001] Checking need to trigger auto leader balancing (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
kafka_1              | [2019-05-24 22:34:06,529] DEBUG [Controller id=1001] Preferred replicas by broker Map(1001 -> Map(__consumer_offsets-22 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-30 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-8 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-21 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-4 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-27 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-7 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-9 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-46 -> Vector(1001), http-ingest-log-4.http-0 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-25 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-35 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-41 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-33 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-23 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-49 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-47 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-16 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-28 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-31 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-36 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-42 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-3 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-18 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-37 -> Vector(1001), http-ingest-log-3.http-0 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-15 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-24 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-38 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-17 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-48 -> Vector(1001), __confluent.support.metrics-0 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-19 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-11 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-13 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-2 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-43 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-6 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-14 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-20 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-0 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-44 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-39 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-12 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-45 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-1 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-5 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-26 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-29 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-34 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-10 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-32 -> Vector(1001), __consumer_offsets-40 -> Vector(1001))) (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
kafka_1              | [2019-05-24 22:34:11,269] DEBUG [Controller id=1001] Topics not in preferred replica for broker 1001 Map() (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
kafka_1              | [2019-05-24 22:34:11,993] TRACE [Controller id=1001] Leader imbalance ratio for broker 1001 is 0.0 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
kafka_1              | [2019-05-24 22:34:23,483] INFO Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 58623ms for sessionid 0x10001d6560e0001, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
mysql_1              | 2019-05-24T22:35:19.628193Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 4049ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)
...
(several minutes later)
...
dataflow-server exited with code 137
```

I get the same behavior when swapping out different parts of the stack; for example RabbitMQ for Kafka/Zookeeper, Postgres for MySQL.

My local stack:

- OSX 10.14
- Java openjdk 11.0.2
- Docker engine 18.09.2
- Docker Compose 1.23.2
- Docker Machine 0.16.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataflow-server` was failing silently due to memory issues. I raised the docker memory limit to 16 GB and stream deployment worked, but the "Runtime" page (http://localhost:9393/dashboard/#/runtime/apps) is still inaccessible. Separate issue tho!

Answer (score 0):

The Docker Compose console won't include the exact reasoning as to what failed and why.

When the stream is deploying, you could view the application logs with the following command.

> docker exec -it skipper tail -f /path/from/stdout/textbox/in/dashboard

That would indicate whether or not the applications start and specific reasoning, which would help in troubleshooting.

Comment: hello, I was trying this but when I use this command it just removes the directory I am pointing at in the cmd.exe window. Does this command move the stdout file somewhere on my machine or should it be displaying something in the command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

To build on Sabby Anandans answer, if you want to get the logs for a specific cloud stream application, I found that you can mount the volume for the skipper server.  I believe when running on docker, all of the spring data flow stream applications write logs out to a tmp directory. If you open up the application that failed to deploy it will tell you where it logs out the file. It should be something like...

/tmp/[RANDOM ID]/[NAME OF APPLICATION PLUS RUN VERSION]/stdout_0.log

So if you just mount a volume for the tmp folder to your skipper container, it should write out the logs. Make sure you mount to skipper-server and not dataflow-server. Dataflow-server also writes to this directory but it does not write the logs.

In my docker-compose.yml file, under skipper-server:

```
volumes:
  - C:\dataflow\output\logs:/tmp
```

So after restarting my dataflow server by doing a docker-compose up, I was able to get logs out for my failing application at...

C:\dataflow\output\logs\1581698212231\streamName.applicationName-v1\